# Debugging on Android Disgo 8100 tablet

Tags: android

I've got a Disgo 8100 tablet which I would like to test an app on but I'm having problems doing anything with it. I'm new to Android development but I've got 2 phones setup and connected and working with Eclipse. The Disgo is running 2.3.3 but there is no USB debugging option under Settings -> Applications and when I connect the device to the USB all I get is a drive mounted and no device listed in adb. Device manager also shows a disk rather than a device so I can't update the driver.

What can I do to get this working?

Comment: it seems you can't connect via usb but there might be ways to do adb over wifi like http://www.androidtablets.net/forum/sylvania-tablets/4229-how-get-working-google-market.html

Answer (score 0):

If the device has an option to allow installation of non market applications, then you can select this.

Once that is done, creat an apk for your app in eclipse, then when the device is mounted
as a drive, just transfer the apk file to the device in a tmp folder.

Once you have done this, you need to locate the file on the device (using a file explorer such as astro), and run it. 
This will install the app onto the device, although you wont be able to debug, you will be able to see if the app runs ok.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to look deepper in settings, may be USB debugging option on in App. section. For example on my Galaxy S2 ICS it's in Development section.
After it you should install drivers for your device